# setInterval on function onkeydown

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I want to perform the space-bar key (keycode 32) and run setInterval many times. But now I can only get the space-bar to work 1 time.

I want to break out off setInterval. When I put space-bar key again, setInterval should run again.

```
document.onkeydown = function onkeydown(event) {

  if (event.keyCode == 65) {
    if (PosPlayN >= 150) {
      PosPlayN -= 5;
    }       
  }

  if (event.keyCode == 68) {
    if (PosPlayN <= 200) {
      PosPlayN += 5;
    }
  }

  if (event.keyCode == 32) {

    var jump = setInterval(jumplp, 5);

    function jumplp() {

      if (jumpcheck <= 30) {
        PosPlayN -= 2;
      }

      if (jumpcheck >= 31 && jumpcheck <= 60) {
        PosPlayN += 2;
      }

      if (jumpcheck >= 60) {
        // ----- I want to exit setInterval here -----
      }

      jumpcheck+=1;
    }
  }

  if (event.keyCode == 17) {
    pGo = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to completely prevent spacebar action after `jumcheck > 60`, where this variable initialized?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: i have answer .thx every one

Answer (score 3):

```
if(jumpcheck >=60){
    clearInterval(jump);
}
```

Comment: if(jumpcheck >=60){ clearInterval(jump); } ------------------------------------- can't put space-bar again.It only first time. –

Comment: That would probably be because jumpcheck is a global variable, so it always exits immediately the following times. Try this: `var jumpcheck = 0; var jump = setInterval(jumplp,5); function jumplp()...`